# databricks avro schema cannot be converted to a Spark SQL structtype

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, databricks, spark-avro

we have kakfa hdfs connector writing into hdfs in default avro format. A sample o/p:

> Obj^A^B^Vavro.schema"["null","string"]^@$Í³ø{<9d>¾Ã^X:<8d>uV^K^H5^F°^F^B<8a>^B{"severity":"notice","message":"Test message","facility":"kern","syslog-tag":"sawmill_test:","timestamp":"2017-01-31T20:15:00+00:00"}^B<8a>^B{"severity":"notice","message":"Test message","facility":"kern","syslog-tag":"sawmill_test:","timestamp":"2017-01-31T20:15:00+00:00"}^B<8a>^B{"severity":"notice","message":"Test message","facility":"kern","syslog-tag":"sawmill_test:","timestamp":"2017-01-31T20:15:00+00:00"}$Í³ø{<9d>¾Ã^X:<8d>uV^K^H5

Trying to read using:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
    val df = spark.read.avro("..path to avro file")
```

we get the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Avro schema cannot be converted to a Spark SQL StructType:
>   [ "null", "string" ]
>     at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource.inferSchema(DefaultSource.scala:93)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:184)
>     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:183)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:135)
>     at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameReader$$anonfun$avro$2.apply(package.scala:34)
>     at com.databricks.spark.avro.package$AvroDataFrameReader$$anonfun$avro$2.apply(package.scala:34)

Please help

Spark version: 2.11

Spark-avro version: 2.11-3.2.0

kafka version: 0.10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

your file in avro format is not proper. The schema must be type:record.  Am unable to attach a valid avro format file sorry for that. 
But you can refer this link. [Sample Avro format file](https://github.com/miguno/avro-cli-examples/blob/master/twitter.avro)

```
avro.schema¨{"type":"record"
```

And from spark what ever you have done is fine.

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
sqlContext.read.avro(..paht of file)
```